# Windows Subsystem for Linux - Include path for Visual Studio 2019 IntelliSens

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Apologies if this is trivial.

I am working on a C++ project using *Windows Subsystem for Linux*. There is no issue compiling and debugging the project, but IntelliSense does not see the libraries I have installed and gives me a lot of warnings/errors:

[image: VS Error List]

Where is the `lib` folder for *Windows Subsystem for Linux*?

Comment: When you say it compiles successfully, is that when you build from the command-line (and what compiler?) - or does it build fine in VS too, but the errors still display? What's in the "Source" column of the Errors List (it might be hidden, right-click to show it)

Comment: @Dai It builds fine in VS too. It's just IntelliSense cannot see those header files, which is the source for those errors.

Comment: Where do you install those libraries? in the WSL OS filesystem?

Comment: @GhasemRamezani Yes.

Comment: @iManBiglari, So, I didn't find any relevant documentation about remote addressing the PATH for Visual Studio. But [here is one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-vscode) for Visual Studio Code.

Comment: For Visual Studio: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-with-visual-studio-2019-and-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl/

Comment: @GhasemRamezani This would require SSH connection to WSL which I have not configured. Visual Studio has no problem invoking GCC for WSL without a remote connection, so I was hoping for a smarter solution.